# Extending bundles in Symfony2 BeSimpleSoapBundle

Tags: php, web-services, symfony, soap, wsdl

I'm working on my first "real" Symfony project which is a SOAP api. I have found the BeSimple SoapBundle and I want to add a few complex types to it that seem to be unsupported by the bundle. Amongst others I want to override the following function that is in the Dumper class:

```
protected function addComplexType(ComplexType $type)
{

}
```

It's located here: besimple/soap-wsdl/BeSimple/SoapWsdl/Dumper/Dumper.php

What I did is the following.

I created src/Webstuff/SoapBundle/SoapWsdl/Dumper/Dumper.php

That contains:

```
<?php
namespace Webstuff\SoapBundle\SoapWsdl\Dumper;

use BeSimple\SoapWsdl\Dumper as BaseDumper;
use BeSimple\SoapCommon\Definition\Definition;

class Dumper extends BaseDumper
{

    public function __construct(Definition $definition, array $options = array())
    {
        echo 'CHECK';
        exit;
    }

}

?>
```

I have also added this to the WebstuffSoapBundle.php

```
public function getParent(){
    return 'BeSimpleSoapBundle';
}
```

When visiting my wsdl path I would expect to see CHECK. But it's just loading the wsdl so this setup isn't working. I'm quite new to Symfony so I might be missing something obvious.

Hopefully someone can give me a push in the right direction! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to:
I. Extend the `WebServiceContext` (located as: **besimple/soap/src/BeSimple/SoapBundle/WebServiceContext.php**), so as to be able to use your dumper in "`getWsdlFile`" method instead of the parent dumper.

E.g.:

```
<?php 
//Overriding WebServiceContext

namespace Webstuff\SoapBundle;

use Webstuff\SoapBundle\SoapWsdl\Dumper\Dumper;
use Symfony\Component\Config\ConfigCache;

class WebServiceContext extends \BeSimple\SoapBundle\WebServiceContext
{
private $options;

public function __construct($loader, $converters, $options)
{
    $this->options = $options;
    return  parent::__construct($loader,$converters,$options);
}

public function getWsdlFile($endpoint = null)
{
    $file      = sprintf ('%s/%s.%s.wsdl', $this->options['cache_dir'], $this->options['name'], md5($endpoint));

    $cache = new ConfigCache($file, $this->options['debug']);
    if(!$cache->isFresh()) {
        $definition = $this->getServiceDefinition();

        if ($endpoint) {
            $definition->setOption('location', $endpoint);
        }

        $dumper = new Dumper($definition, array('stylesheet' => $this->options['wsdl_stylesheet']));

        $cache->write($dumper->dump());
    }
    return (string) $cache;
}
}
?php>
```

II. Set "`besimple.soap.context.class`" parameter in `config.yml` to refer to your class that extends `WebServiceContext`.

E.g.:

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
besimple.soap.context.class: "Webstuff\SoapBundle\WebServiceContext"
```